# REST API chat - endpoint for real-time fetching messages

Tags: node.js, api, rest, websocket, chat

I have a REST API server powered by express+mongodb. There are a couple of endpoints with different resources. One of them is chat API. I already have several basic endpoints like:

- `POST http://api.example.com/v1/chat` - to create chat
- `POST http://api.example.com/v1/chat/:id/message` - to send message to existing chat
- `GET http://api.example.com/v1/chat/:id/messages` - to get messages in the the specified chat

But I need to provide a way for API consumers to efficiently get new messages **in real-time** without reloading the page.

For now as you see it's possible just to poll `GET` endpoint from client but it seems not performant. *For example client can have UI which will show new messages count in header (some kind of notifications)*.

I was thinking about websockets. Is it possible for example to provide endpoint like `/chat/:id/subscribe` which will proxy sockets' server and connect to it on client?

Is there some good examples of such API design where I can get inspiration from or maybe you can give me piece of advice? Thanks!

Comment: seems a good case to use websockets. Socket.io has node.js support

Comment: Checkout this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/38558531/2506522

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[socket.io](http://socket.io/docs/#) is the package you are looking for.

The [namespace](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace) section in it's documentation is a good solution because namespaces can be authorization protected. It represents a pool of connected sockets.

Here is how I would do it :

Create a document for the chat between the two users with this route :

```
POST http://api.example.com/v1/chat
```

Create a namespace with socket.io when a user sends a message to another connected user and store it into your user's document in your database. This route would create a namespace and/or emit  the message :

```
POST http://api.example.com/v1/chat/:id/message
```

In the client, you have to use socket.io again to listen to the messages in the namespace.

**UPDATE FOR SCALABILITY :**

Here is a good stackoverflow answered question about implementing a scalable chat server : [Strategy to implement a scalable chat server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186043/strategy-to-implement-a-scalable-chat-server)

As you can see in this post, mongodb might not be the best solution to store your messages.

Comment: what about scalability?

Comment: I updated my answer. There is a good stackoverflow post talking about this. I added a link.v