# Need to know something regarding socket.io and redis and nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io, node-redis, socket.io-1.0

My goal is to build a chat application - similar to whatsapp

To my understanding, socket.io is a real-time communication library written in javascript and it is very simple to use

For example

```
 // Serverside
    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.on('chat', function(msg) {
            io.emit('chat', msg);
      });
    });

 // ClientSide (Using jquery)

   var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });

  socket.on('chat', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });
```

1)  do I always need to start an `io.on('connection')` to use the real-time feature or i could just start using `socket.on` object instead? for example i have a route

```
app.post('/postSomething', function(req, res) {
    // Do i need to start an io.on or socket.on here?

});
```

because i want the real-time feature to be listen only on specific route.

2) Redis is a data structure library which handles the pub/sub, why do we need to use pub/sub mechanism? 
I read alot of articles but couldn't grasp the concept. Article example http://ejosh.co/de/2015/01/node-js-socket-io-and-redis-intermediate-tutorial-server-side/

for example the code below

```
// Do i need redis for this, if so why? is it for caching purposes?
// Where does redis fit in this code?


 var redis = require("redis");
 var client = redis.createClient();


 io.on('connection', function(socket) {
     socket.on('chat', function(msg) {
          io.emit('chat', msg);
      }); 
  });
```

3) Just wondering why I need nginx to scale node.js application? i found this stackoverflow answer:
[Strategy to implement a scalable chat server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186043/strategy-to-implement-a-scalable-chat-server)

It says something about load balancing, read that online and couldn't grasp the concept as well.

So far I have only been dealing with node.js , mongoose simple CRUD application, but I'm willing work really hard if you guys could share some of your knowledge and share some useful resources so that I could deepen my knowledge about all of these technologies.

Cheers!

Comment: You have 3 questions; post them as three separate questions on stack overflow, this will help you get answers

Comment: @BasitAnwer the reason why i ask everything in one question because I have to wait for 90 minutes for every question

Comment: @BasitAnwer if you could help me and answer the question, it would be really helpful

Comment: Answered; but please refrain from doing that. If someone knows the answer of 2 out of 3 questions, he/she might be hesitant to answer your complete question plus its against SO rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Q. Socket.on without IO.on**

```
io.on("connection" ... )
```

Is called when you receive a new connection. Socket.on listens to all the emits at the client side. If you want your client to act as a server for some reason then (in short) yes io.on is required

> **Q. Redis pub/sub vs Socket.IO**

Take a look at this [SO question/anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929700/what-should-i-be-using-socket-io-rooms-or-redis-pub-sub), quoting;

> Redis pub/sub is great in case all clients have direct access to redis. If you have multiple node servers, one can push a message to the others.
>
> But if you also have clients in the browser, you need something else to push data from a server to a client, and in this case, socket.io is great.
>
> Now, if you use socket.io with the Redis store, socket.io will use Redis pub/sub under the hood to propagate messages between servers, and servers will propagate messages to clients.
>
> So using socket.io rooms with socket.io configured with the Redis store is probably the simplest for you.

Redis can act like a message queue if it is a requirement. Redis is a datastore support many datatypes.

> **Q. Why Nginx with Node.js**

Node.js can work standalone but nginx is faster to server static content.

Since nginx is a reverse proxy therefore servers are configured with nginx to handle all the static data (serving static files, doing redirects, handling SSL certificates and serving error pages.
) and every other request is sent to node.js

Check this Quora post as well: [Should I host a node.js project without nginx?](https://www.quora.com/Should-I-host-a-node-js-project-without-nginx)
Quoting:

> Nginx can be used to remove some load from the Node.js processes, for example, serving static files, doing redirects, handling SSL certificates and serving error pages.
>
> You can do everything without Nginx but it means You have to code it yourself, so why not use a fast and proven solution for this.